# How can I get Skype Video working on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, skype

I understand it requires, libv4l1 but I cannot get 32bit version for it, for some reason from `apt-get`.

```
locate libv4l
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access/libv4l2_plugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l2.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert0/ov511-decomp
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert0/ov518-decomp
```

... and so on.

Comment: Why do you want the 32-bit version on a 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is

```
sudo apt get install libv4l-0:i386
```

to get the i386 in a 64bit system.